# R- Reading a frequently updated file with R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a json file that is frequently updated. 
In a normal situation, this is how I would read the file if it was just a one time thing:

```
json_data <- fromJSON(file="file.json")
```

or

```
jfile <- stream_in(file("file.json"))
```

This is obviously not going to work in my case as I want to set a case where R checks if the file has been updated and pulls the changes.
Is  it also possible to also set a check time o some sorts?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for file modification time and only re-load the file when it has changed. You could perhaps fetch only the last n new entries in the file but I think it is not safe to assume a json file grows incrementally.

```
require(jsonlite)

# some json file on disk
jfile = tempfile()
cat( toJSON(mtcars[1:3, ]), file = jfile)

# initial fetch of the file and of its modification time
nfo1 = file.info(jfile)$mtime
d = fromJSON(jfile)
d

# new lines are added to jfile from an external process 
# (here just cat)
cat( toJSON(mtcars[1:4, ]), file = jfile )

#check see if file is modified and load it again
nfo2 = file.info(jfile)$mtime

if(nfo2 > nfo1)
    d = fromJSON(jfile)
d
```